# Can't add CSS animation to list items on touchstart event

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, touch-event

I have some simple CSS animation to occur when a touch start event is detected however keep getting "undefined is not an object" when trying to add a class to a div element. Please check this on mobile as it's activated through a touch event. I want to add a class with new value to all the li items inside a div. I tried console logging each list item before adding the class and prints in the console fine. it's pretty straightforward but i cant figure out why I'm getting this error only when adding the class. The CSS for animations needs to only occur on mobile so i added those new class in the media queries.

Here's the [working website](https://kerlerone-animated.netlify.app).

```js
container.addEventListener('touchstart', handlePanStart, false);

function handlePanStart() {
  const target = document.querySelectorAll('.top')
  let yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
  console.log('start', 'ypos: ' + yOffset)

  target.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.classList)
    item.classlist.add('longer')

  })
}
```

```css
ul {
  height: 50vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.top {
  height: 5px;
  width: 95vw;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

.top img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid black;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.longer {
  height: 205px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
  <li class="top"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why `touchstart`? Why not also `mouseover`?

Comment: @Dai Phones, tablets?

Comment: @DreamTeK  Desktops, laptops, non-touchscreen phones, etc _don't_ raise the `touchstart` event. I want to know why the OP is seemingly deliberately excluding those classes of users from this functionality on their webpage. Conversely, touchscreen devices _will_ still raise the `mouseover` event on touch input if `touchstart` isn't already added, so choosing to _only_ listen to `touchstart` is perplexing.

Comment: Hi @DreamTeK - I only added the code snippet for mobile - I have a perfectly working version for desktop and laptop etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `classlist` to `classList` (camel-case). `classlist` is undefined in the DOM.

Comment: Typo questions should be flagged for closure. They don't add value to the community. A comment will suffice.